# ArrayList - Index vs Size

Tags: java

I received the following error when trying to print an ArrayList of 698 items:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 698, Size: 698
```

I used the following code which I expected to get an error for:

```
 Mylist.top(1000);
```

My question is, if the size of the array is 698, then shouldn't the max index be 697? I don't understand why the error gives Index: 698.

Comment: The error is saying that you tried to access index 698, which doesn't exist

Comment: That's precisely what the error is saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if the size of the array is 698, then shouldn't the max index be 697? I don't understand why the error gives Index: 698.

That's exactly *why* it's an error.

The error is `IndexOutOfBoundsException`; it means you tried to access an invalid index. This would be one that is less than zero or greater than the max. As you correctly noted, `697` is the max index for an array of 698 items... so trying to access index `698` throws an exception.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense, thanks! Obviously was just a simple question but nice to understand the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raising when you are trying to access index 698. You are right, max index is 697, so error will raise in the following index.